# size of string returned by malloc is not correct

Tags: c

Why the size of the following allocated string (i.e. `result`) is not correct in the following code

```
#include <stdlib.h>


char *concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *result;

    result = malloc( strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1 );

    printf("%d", sizeof(result)); // <-- ????? ( it should be seven)

    if ( result == NULL ){
        printf("Error: malloc failed in concat\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcpy(result, s2);


    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char *p;
    p = concat("abc", "def");

    return 0;
}
```

---

Edit:
I'm trying to allocate an enough size for the new string but for somehow the size is not correct.

Comment: typo `strcpy(result, s2);` --> `strcat(result, s2);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, you are certainly right. I completely forgot about that and I was digging in the wrong place.

Comment: result is a pointer, sizeof(apointer) is 4 on a 32 bit architecture and 8 on a 64 bit architecture.  getting the size of a pointer says nothing about the size of what is being pointed to.

Comment: Note: The _type_ return by `sizeof` is `size_t` which may/may not be the same size as `int`.  Use `printf("%zu", sizeof result)`  ( this is not your major problem though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time, and it pays no attention to the size of the allocated block.

The expression returns the size of pointer, which is fixed for the hardware platform.

Unfortunately, there is no way of finding the allocated size returned by `malloc`. If you want to know the size of an allocated block, you need to store the size in a separate variable.

Comment: Is there any case `sizeof` is evaluated at runtime?

Comment: but when I use `strlen(result)`, I am still not getting the correct size of the new string.

Comment: @iharob Yes, it is evaluated at runtime when you pass a variable-length array, e.g. `int n = ...; int a[n]; printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(a));`

Comment: @CroCo You can't fetch the size allocated with malloc. You have to remember the size yourself, in a separate variable if you need it. If you copy a string into the allocated buffer, you can find the length of that string though, with `strlen()`

Comment: The C standard doesn't distinguish compile time vs runtime. So, in theory, even `sizeof(int)` could be evaluated at runtime. Of course, you have to find a terrible compiler to achieve that :)

Comment: @CroCo This is because `strlen` counts characters until `'\0'`. The length is not going to match unless there's the correct number of of non-null characters in the block, followed by `'\0'`.

Comment: @Blue Moon: While it is true that C standard does not use terms "compile-time" or "run-time", it still has concepts of *constant* and *integer constant expression*, which is actually intended to stand for "compile-time constant". This is the expression you are required to use as a bit-field width, for one example. And `sizeof(int)` is guaranteed to be a *integer constant expression*, meaning that it can always be used as width in a bit-field declaration (or a case label, or an initializer for a static object).

Comment: This makes is rather obvious that `sizeof(int)` is guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time. `sizeof` can be a run-time value with VLAs, but in all other cases it is explicitly guaranteed to be a constant by language standard.

Comment: @AndreyT The question is not whether `sizeof(int)` yields a integer constant expression (which it is) but whether it's required to be evaluated at compile time. My previous comment still applies. *[..]which is actually intended to stand for "compile-time constant".* is your interpretation I think, not necessarily define so by the standard. The closet the standard has in relation to this is "translation phase 4", which again doesn't define anything explicitly or clearly.

Comment: To put it otherwise, if a compiler evaluates `sizeof(int)` at runtime, can it considered to be violating any constraints/non-conforming to the C spec? AFAICT, the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(result)` will give the size of a pointer probably `4` or `8`, so you cant use it for that.

Immediately after calling `malloc` you should check it's return value, on error it returns `NULL`, if the value is not `NULL` then it points to uninitialized content.

To get the length of a string you need `strlen` function, but if the contents are not initialised it would be undefined behavior.

You need to use `strlen` after you fill the buffer with data, the data is terminated with a `'\0'` byte which marks the end of the string, it wouldn't be there if you haven't initialized the data.

Comment: but when I use `strlen(result)`, I am still not getting the correct size of the new string.

Comment: @CroCo: You don't have a *string*. A *string* in C is defined as a continuous sequence of characters terminated by a zero character. Your block of memory after `malloc` contains uninitialized garbage. Uninitialized garbage is not a string. You are not allowed to apply `strlen` to uninitialized garbage. It is not possible to query the size of a block of memory in standard C (if that's what you are trying to do). You have to remembr the size manually.

Comment: @AndreyT, you are right but even after checking the size before `return` in the my function, I am still not getting the correct size.

Comment: @CroCo: I don't know what size you consider "correct". Your function, as written above, does not perform concatenation. It simply copies two strings into the same memory area. The second string overwrites the first one. So, `strlen` before `return` will give you the length of the second string. In that sense it is perfectly correct. If you want to perform concatenation, you should replace the second `strcpy` with `strcat`. This is not the best way to implement concatenation, but it will work.

Comment: @user300234  Concerning "non-NULL" return, certainly the _allocation_ was successful, but that does not mean valid memory is usable via that pointer until it actually happens successfully as I believe you comment suggests.  [Linux follows an optimistic memory allocation strategy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)